# WPF XAML database driven checkbox values

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xaml, checkbox

how do I display an unknown number of checkboxes in XAML? I'm querying the database to extract a list of possible values, and then I want to display those values as a list of checkboxes.  Some DB tables may have a small number of values, others could potentially have 100+.

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SuppliersSearchStatusListBox" Margin="100,100,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" AllowDrop="True" MaxHeight="50" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ListStatusOptions}">
  <CheckBox Content="{Binding arrStatusOption}"/>
</ListBox>
```

CS:

```
public void ListStatusOptions()
{
    // Query, vars and debug info removed
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQLQuery, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "StatusOptions");

    int varArrCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    string[] arrStatusOption = new string[varArrCount];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        arrStatusOption[i] = dr["StatusValue"].ToString();
        i++;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

The DB query returns results into the array and the values are as expected, but a list of checkboxes do not appear on the XAML page.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use data templates to template each item in the ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SuppliersSearchStatusListBox"
         scrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
         AllowDrop="True"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ListStatusOptions}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding arrStatusOption}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then change ListStatusOptions to a new class with an IsSelected property to bind to instead of just strings

```
public class StatusOption
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your code to use this new class

```
public void ListStatusOptions()
{
    // Query, vars and debug info removed
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQLQuery, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "StatusOptions");

    int varArrCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    var arrStatusOption = new StatusOption[varArrCount];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        arrStatusOption[i] = new StatusOption
                                 {
                                     Name = dr["StatusValue"].ToString(),
                                     IsSelected = false
                                 }
        i++;
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can't profess to understand the changes, but that's the joy of learning and keeps Wrox press going :-)